# HttpURLConnection read InputStream twice

Tags: java, android, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I make a http get request to server via `HttpURLConnection` and I need to read response (`InputStream`) twice: for logging purposes and for parsing response. The returned `InputStraem` is instance of `org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.ChunkedInputStream` which doesn't support marking (`is.markSupported()` return `false`).

Therefore I can't `mark()` and `reset()` stream and after writing response in log I can't parse it. Ofcourse I can read response once into `String` or something else, log them and later parse. But when i'm working with streams i'm avoiding potentially `OutOfMemomryError` because streams deals with buffering instead of me.

What is the best solution in this case which will keep the benefits of using streams and help to achieve the desired result: the simultaneous recording into the log and parsing response?

**EDIT:** Solution with writing response into temporary file isn't appropriate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand, you'd like to read the `InputStream` once (not really twice that's a bit unclean IMO, because what if an error occurs only on the log stream and not the stream you are parsing?) and then simply log and parse the same `InputStream`?

If the above is the case here pseudo to show the solution:

```
InputStream is=...;
byte[] bytes=new byte[1028];
while(is.read(bytes)!=-1) {
log(bytes); //call function to log
parse(bytes);//call function to parse
}
```

even better for simultaneous logging and recording would be creating a new `Thread`/`Runnable` for both methods, starting them and wait for them to return using (`thread.join();`):

```
InputStream is=...;
byte[] bytes=new byte[1028];
while(is.read(bytes)!=-1) {
Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          log(bytes); //call function to log
        }
    });
Thread t2=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           parse(bytes);//call function to parse
        }
    });
     t1.start();
     t2.start();
try {
     t1.join();
     t2.join();
    }catch(Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to get access to full stream content twice (content is string in JSON format): first - just to write it in log and second - to parse response

Comment: Either way, once you have the `String` in JSON format pass it to the method that *decodes* it, then pass the returned `String` to `log()` and `parse()`. Really bad to read a Stream twice as I mentioned and another answer

Comment: Code is flawed. It ignores the result of `read()`, so it is liable to process junk at the end of each buffer.

Comment: That doesn't even compile. It should be `log(bytes, 0, count);` and `parse(bytes, 0, count);` where `count` is the `int` result of the `read()` method.

Comment: Im not sure I understand that have a look at the docs here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29

Comment: I'm familiar with the Javadoc for java.io. What exactly didn't you understand?

Answer (score 2):

You should never need to read an input stream twice. Log it as you read it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know in advance the potential size of the stream (or if it's too big to be put in a `String` or a `byte[]`), then I would use the `InputStream` of the `HttpURLConnection` to log (possibly in a separate file if you need to) and I would use the log file for the parsing purpose.

This is probably not the most efficient way of duplicating an `InputStream` but probably one of the safest memory wise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this solution is too slow and bulky(